# Removing class from dynamic assembly / module

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, reflection.emit, system.reflection

I am working on emitting a class that is based on user's input. Dynamic classes are convenient, since user is free to comeback later and change the input, and program will re-emit new class.

If user comes back later and decides to make some changes, existing class that is already in the assembly/module needs to flushed. How to remove the dynamic class ?

Answer (score 3):

Try to create dynamic assembly for each dynamic class you are generating. In that case you can simply unload the dynamic assembly as needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can't... You could unload the dynamic assembly you created, if you used the [`AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndCollect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.reflection.emit.assemblybuilderaccess.aspx), but you would need to be sure that there are no references to it (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd554932.aspx)